How does the Greek- to- English translation of Sirach 10:9-10 go, and what is its intent?
We read in Sirach 10:9-10 (NRSVA):

How can dust and ashes be proud?
Even in life the human body decays.
A long illness baffles the physician;
the king of today will die tomorrow.

Footnotes uder the Verses say that the meaning of the original Greek text is uncertain. My question is: How does the Greek-to-English translation of Sirach 10:9-10 go, and what is its intent ?

It means that mortal flesh decays to death, a tough illness baffles a physician, and rulers come and go.
